# \subimport and \includegraphics compatibility issue

Tags: graphics, compiling, import

I am trying to `\subimport` a `content.tex` document into a larger `thesis.tex` document. All works well with importing text and tikz files, but I am getting the following error when trying to import `\includegraphics{picture.png}` which is called from the `content.tex` file.

```
Unable to load picture or PDF file
```

I've looked at a number of SO answers, but can't find anyone else who is having this problem.

I think that the problem might be coming from the fact that my `\includegraphics{}` call is trying to find a file that is in a different directory than that which contains my `content.tex`. Specifically, I use the `..` convention to navigate to a different directory, i.e. `\includegraphics{../../figs/picture.png}`.

Any thoughts would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`\subimport` doesn't update `\includegraphics`, and the path is relative to the master `.tex` rather then the nested imported file.